# Jabra Elite 65t? Call quality?

Tags: sound, bluetooth, skype

has anyone tried to pair the [Jabra Elite 65t bluetooth in-ears](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i8G8LKT-G8w) with Linux?

I am thinking about the purchase but both A2DP and [HFP with Wide Band Speech (mSBC)](http://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=238193) in Debian (Ubuntu) are a must - I want to use them not only for playing music, but also for quality audio conferencing (Skype, Hangouts) in open plan.

Thanks in advance for sharing the experience!

Comment: Hey Alice! Did you ever get these headphones? Does the microphone work on Linux?

Comment: @radu.ciorba I bought them but I use them only with Android or in ADP while using analog headphones/mic for calls with Linux.Only now I tried that... to learn that when I want to use the microphone in HFP, it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Well... the microphone in HFP doesn't work at all in Linux. Not even in lousy quality. I can use it in A2DP to listen a call while using any analog microphone.
2. Further research showed we depend with sound quality on having mSBC in Pulse Audio at all.

   This is to watch: [PulseAudio > Merge requests > bluetooth: add support of mSBC codec to HFP profile](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/merge_requests/254)

   The original question may also appear obsolete with advent of more standards.
   For example: what is also worth checking is FastStream. See [ValdikSS: "Audio over Bluetooth: most detailed information about profiles, codecs, and devices". June 2019. Habr.com](https://habr.com/en/post/456182/)

Comment: Thanks for the followup! I was hopeful about these since somehow my "Jabra Evolve 75" just worked out of the box. I did not realize how complicated Bluetooth audio is :)

Comment: HFP works fine for me on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I have had success with the Jabra 65t Active headphones and Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.  I am using a Lenovo Y 50-70 Laptop.

The sound quality while listening to the linux Spotify application seems equal to my phone, perhaps with better range due to the laptop's, obsolete, Bluetooth 4.0 hardware.
~~~~~
So:

1.Music and all audio seem to work great.  Phone and computer can be connected receiving audio simultaneously.

2. Microphone? I haven't tried this function yet.  I'm curious to hear if you come up with anything!

Comment: Well, after Jabra released the professional Evolve version guaranteed to work with Windows for "only" 362 Eur, I think I'll go buy Elite and check myself.